# Typescript: Create an object with multidimensional properties

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

quick question: I want to create a object with some multidimensional properties.

The user class have properties such as have a sex, birthdate, height.

But also multidimensional property for weight, where the user can add his new weight at with the current date.

```
interface weightData {
    date: Date;
    weight: number;
}

export class UserData {
    sex: string;
    location:string;
    fokus:string;
    birthdate:Date;
    weight:Array<weightData> = [];
    height:number;

    constructor(sex:string, location:string, fokus:string, birthdate:Date, height:number, weight:number) {
        let currentDate: Date = new Date();

        this.sex = sex;
        this.location = location;
        this.fokus = fokus;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight.push(
            date: currentDate, //dont work
            weight: 31 // dont work
        );
    }
}
```

My 2 Problems here:

1: Whats the right syntax for the constructor?

2: Whats the best way to create a method which adds a new value to "weight"?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can skip the big init overhead with public fields. And add some `addWeight` function for your needs. I created a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mhj0WO5u4oJCVIVkcYGO?p=preview).

Main part here:

```
interface weightData {
    date: Date;
    weight: number;
}

export class UserData {

    // fields are created public by default
    constructor(public sex:string = 'female', public location:string = 'us', public fokus:string = 'none', public birthdate:Date = new Date(), public height:number = 1, public weight:Array<weightData> = []) {}

    // Date optional, use new Date() if not provided
    addWeight(amount: number, date?: Date = new Date()) {
      this.weight.push({date, amount})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
class UserData {
    sex: string;
    location: string;
    fokus: string;
    birthdate: Date;
    weight: weightData[];
    height: number;

    constructor(sex: string, location: string, fokus: string, birthdate: Date, height: number, weight: number | weightData) {
        this.sex = sex;
        this.location = location;
        this.fokus = fokus;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.height = height;

        this.weight = [];
        this.addWeight(weight);
    }

    addWeight(weight: number | weightData) {
        if (typeof weight === "number") {
            this.weight.push({
                date: new Date(),
                weight: weight
            });
        } else {
            this.weight.push(weight);
        }
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20weightData%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20date%3A%20Date%3B%0A%20%20%20%20weight%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20class%20UserData%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20sex%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20location%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20fokus%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20birthdate%3A%20Date%3B%0A%20%20%20%20weight%3A%20weightData%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20height%3A%20number%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(sex%3A%20string%2C%20location%3A%20string%2C%20fokus%3A%20string%2C%20birthdate%3A%20Date%2C%20height%3A%20number%2C%20weight%3A%20number%20%7C%20weightData)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.sex%20%3D%20sex%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.location%20%3D%20location%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.fokus%20%3D%20fokus%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.birthdate%20%3D%20birthdate%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.height%20%3D%20height%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.weight%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.addWeight(weight)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20addWeight(weight%3A%20number%20%7C%20weightData)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20weight%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22number%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.weight.push(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20date%3A%20new%20Date()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20weight%3A%20weight%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.weight.push(weight)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))